# Flutter JsonSerializable correct way to create Firestore Sub Collection?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to start working with Firebase Firestore sub-collections in my Flutter mobile app. I'm using JsonSerializable and JsonAnnotation packages, but I'm not sure of the correct way to create Firestore sub-collections within the model. I would like sub-collections for users and dogs. Here is my basic model setup.

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class AccountModel {
  String accountName;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: dateTimeFromTimestamp, toJson: dateTimeAsIs)
  DateTime? createdAt;

  AccountModel({
    required this.accountName,
    this.createdAt,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Reads in Firestore are shallow. This means that reading a document from Firestore returns a snapshot of just that document, and never includes the JSON data from the subcollections at the same time.

The same applies to write operations: an API call to Firestore to write a document can never include information for documents in subcollections in the same call.

What you *can* do to write atomically to a parent document and the subcollection is [use a batched write operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). But you still need to make a separate call for each parent/child document, and pass a separate `JsonSerializable` object to each call.

The experimental [Firestore ODM](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/c7e93cfec14e0e00bcabb232760ae5a968a1c2a1/packages/cloud_firestore_odm/doc/subcollections.md) package *does* have support for handling subcollections, so you might want to have a look there.

Comment: what you mention I know I was asking about the correct to have it inside the flutter model class, ideally I was just thinking of doing another class with a refence